# Qt simple note pad, print line number on status bar of QmainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qstatusbar

I have created simple notepad from Qt/C++. I want to print the line number on status bar of `QMainWindow` when I click somewhere on the text area, like notepad of Microsoft Windows

[image: Status bar with line number]

Comment: What have you tried? You just need the current cursor position in the text edit and a way to set text on the status bar. ;)

Comment: is this  QPoint globalCursorPos = QCursor::pos(); valid for current cursor position ,and how can i print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect the [`cursorPositionChanged()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#cursorPositionChanged) signal of your text area to a custom slot of your `QMainWindow`:

```
// the connection
connect(ui->plainTextEdit, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT(showCursorPos()));
// your custom slot
void MainWindow::showCursorPos()
{
    int line = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor().blockNumber()+1;
    int pos = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor().columnNumber()+1;
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString("Ln %1, Col %2").arg(line).arg(pos));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using QTextEdit as the "editor" widget.

To get where is the cursor in your QTextEdit, you should use

```
row = myTextEdit->textCursor()->blockNumber();
```

and for the column

```
column = myTextEdit->textCursor()->positionInBlock();
```

Then just edit your status bar text with these infos

Answer (score 0):

use this code`ui->textEdit->document()->lineCount();`